# Deadlocks and Livelocks issues using @synchronized directive in objective c

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, mutex, synchronized

from the apple's ["Threading Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) I've read that "The best way to avoid both deadlock and livelock situations is to take only one lock at a time". If I prefer to use the @synchronized directive in my code, this means that I should do something like this:

> @synchronized(aObj) {
>
> ```
> @synchronized(bObj) {
>
>     // do sth with the aObj and bObj here     
> }
> ```
>
> }

instead of this:

> @synchronized(aObj, bObj) {
>
> ```
>  // do sth with the aObj and bObj here
> ```
>
> }

?? if not, what it means by "One lock at a time?". Thank you...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to avoid deadlock is to ensure that all threads try to lock and unlock objects in the same order. That's it, really.

By following that one simple rule, the chance of deadlocks is zero.

It doesn't matter whether you try to allocate all the needed locks in one hit or over a significant timeframe, as long as the order is consistent. In other words, don't ever do:

```
Thread A        Thread B
========        ========
lock a          lock b
lock b          lock a
```

This can lead to the sequence:

- A locks a.
- B locks b.
- A tries to lock b, stops and waits.
- B tries to lock a, stops and waits.

Now both threads are waiting on the other to release their needed resource, hence deadlock.

If you change thread `B` so that it locks `a` and `b` in that order, deadlock becomes impossible.

Comment: Totally clear! Thanks. But is my above code (nested use of @synchronized) right to use? Never show nested use of @synchronized and I'm not sure its the right way to use it in order to avoid deadlocks. Or you mean: this is right: `@synchronized(aObj, bObj)` in all the threads, and this is wrong: `@synchronized(aObj, bObj)` in one thread and `@synchronized(bObj, aObj)` in another?

Comment: @Vassilis, I wasn't even aware the multi-object sync was _possible_ in ObjC (my use of the language is moderate but not so use of threading in that language). But my advice stands and it's borne out by the first paragraph under "Watch Out for Deadlocks and Livelocks" in that article you linked to. Provided you acquire locks in the same order in all threads, deadlock is impossible. So is livelock since the situation cannot occur if you're acquiring in the same order.

Comment: Thanks again. Since the @synchronized is just a convenient way to create POSIX Mutex Lock, I assume that both pieces of the code in my question are ok to use since the order is significant in both of them. My doubt was about the use of `@synchronized`, but it seems its ok.

Comment: The sample you give won't give deadlock. so b is locked. So thread a execute to b. Then thread b finish b and A unlock. Tada.

Comment: @Jim, that _will_ give you a deadlock. Consider the following. (1) A locks a. (2) B locks b. (3) A tries to lock b, stops and waits. (4) B tries to lock a, stops and waits. Now both threads are waiting on the other to release their needed resource, hence deadlock. I'll add that to the answer for clarity.

Comment: I thought a and b are serial. It's nested and it's not clear. Somebody need to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Holding multiple locks at the same time immediately raises the specter of deadlock.if two threads acquire the same locks in a different order, they can end up waiting on each other forever.
This problem can be used to solved enforcing the lock order.

```
 @synchronized(MIN(a, b))
    {
        @synchronized(MAX(a, b))
        {
            // do stuff, safely
        }
    }
```

This works with other locking constructs as well. like:

```
 NSLock *a = [[NSLock alloc] init];
    NSLock *b = [[NSLock alloc] init];

    [MIN(a, b) lock];
    [MAX(a, b) lock];

    [MAX(a, b) unlock];
    [MIN(a, b) unlock];
```

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of your code are equally evil and an invitation to a deadlock. What the advice meant is you should write

```
@synchronized (obj1) { ... }
@synchronized (obj2) { ... }
```

You have a potential deadlock if one thread performs nested locks (using one lock, then another) in a different order from another thread. One simple rule to avoid this is to never have two nested locks.